# Filter data based on relation laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have product table like:

```
id | Title     | Price

1    Title 1     5000
2    Product 2   7000
```

this is related to product_attribute table

```
id | product_id | attribute_id | attribute_name | value
 1     1              5             Color         Red
 2     1              6             Size           XL
 3     2              5             Color         Green
```

in product model there is following relation:

```
 public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductsAttribute::class, 'product_id ');
    }
```

In controller method :

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {  
     $attributes=$request->attributes;
     foreach($attributes as $attr)
          {
            $attribute_id=$attr['attribute_id'];
            $attribute_value=$attr['value'];
          }

     return product::with('attributes')
            ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attribute_id,$attribute_value)  {
                $query->where('attribute_id', $attribute_id);
                $query->where('value', $attribute_value);
            })->paginate(10);
    }
```

Issue is in my foreach loop i'm getting multiple attribute_id and attribute_value but in the query i can pass only single value of attribute_id and value. I want to fetch all the products where attribute id and attribute value matches. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Mean $attribute_id and $attribute_value are array

Comment: @Donkarnash: Currently it is a variable but we can make it array if it is possible to fetch from a single query which i'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $attribute_id and $attribute_value are array

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
   /** Assuming that $request->attributes is like
    *
    * $request->attributes = [
    *  ['id' => 1, 'value' => 'Red'],
    *  ['id' => 2, 'value' => 'Xl'],
    *  ['id' => 3, 'value' => 'Green'],
    * ];
    *
    */

   
    $attributes = collect($request->attributes);

    $attribute_id = $attributes->map(function($item){return $item['id'];});

    $attribute_value = $attributes->map(function($item){return $item['value'];});
    
    return Product::with('attributes')
        ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attribute_id,$attribute_value){
            $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attribute_id);
            $query->whereIn('value', $attribute_value);
        })
        ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: In this case, $attribute_id and $attribute_value are the last elements of the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $attributes = $request->all()['attributes'];
        $attributeIds = array_column($attributes, 'attribute_id');
        $attributeValues = array_column($attributes, 'value');

        return product::with('attributes')
            ->whereHas('attributes', function ($query) use ($attributeIds, $attributeValues) {
                $query->whereIn('attribute_id', $attributeIds)
                    ->whereIn('value', $attributeValues);
            })->paginate(10);
    }
```